# Custom Windows 7 Preview Pane syntax highlighting

Tags: windows-7, syntax-highlighting, preview-pane

After [discovering on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/66749/color-coded-windows-7-preview-pane) that there is no current way to add syntax highlighting to the Windows 7 preview pane, I figured if someone else hasn't done it yet then I'll go ahead and do it myself.

Is there an API or SDK available for Windows 7 that exposes the preview pane in explorer to customization?  If so, what is it and how do you think is the most elegant way to accomplish this?  I would like it to read the syntax highlighting options from Visual Studio to get the users favorite colors and code theme settings.

Comment: Love to know if you've followed through on this. I was just searching for this and coming up with nothing so far.

Comment: I started it, but about midway through I lost everything on my little portable hard drive and never managed to find the time to recreate it.  Eventually I'll get around to again and when I do I'm going to push it to bitbucket or github.

Comment: Oh man that's lame. I've recently started using dropbox, and hard-linking my project folder into it so that it gets backed up online automatically every time I close my IDE. Works a treat. Best of luck man.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must check the Preview Handler, you can download an example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940374%28VS.85%29.aspx).
The Preview Handler is used to display a file preview inside the Windows Explorer preview pane or other preview handler hosts.

You can check these links :

- [IPreviewHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775315%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [View Data Your Way With Our Managed Preview Handler Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163487.aspx)
- [Using Vista Preview Handlers in WPF application](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2008/04/18/using-vista-preview-handlers-in-wpf-application.aspx)